# How to install spell check dictionaries in Gedit on Windows

Tags: windows, spell-check, gedit, aspell, hunspell

We are a charity that helps disadvantaged people to get back on track. To this end we provide them with paid occupation. One of them is proof-reading/editing of ancient OCRed texts that we release later under the GNU Free Documentation License. Those people do not have technical background, so we need a super simple text editor. [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) is great for this task. Unfortunately most of those people work on Windows. Gedit being cross-platform helps us here as well. But we can't get Gedit under Windows to spell-check texts. How can we add a dictionary for spell checking in Gedit on Windows? (To be more specific - we need Hebrew spell checking).

Comment: Gedit doesn't support spellcheckers. Alternatively Libreoffice is also free and cross-platform.

Comment: It does. You just have to know how to install the relevant dictionaries and make Gedit aware of them.

Comment: @user1876484 You have to install aspell and link it to gedit. I spend an hour trying to figure it out and gave up (there is no proper documentation).

Comment: @DavidPostill - that is exactly our problem :). Also I'm not sure aspell for Windows has Hebrew.

Comment: @user1876484 Download Hebrew Dictionary from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html, so that bit is sorted at least.

Comment: Which version of gedit are you using?

Comment: Both versions (32bit for tablets). Thank you for providing info for both of them! I'll check it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure to get spell check working is slightly different for the two currently available versions of gedit on Windows. They both support [Hunspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell), [MySpell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySpell), and [Ispell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ispell) dictionaries, but I will focus on Hunspell / MySpell here. (I will have a note about Ispell and [Aspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Aspell) at the end.)

### Downloading dictionaries

The easiest place to find Hunspell / MySpell dictionaries (`*.aff` and `*.dic` files) is from the [LibreOffice dictionaries repo](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/) ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries)). Be sure to download the plain / raw files.

For Hebrew, open these links to download the raw files: [he_IL.aff](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/blob/master/he_IL/he_IL.aff), [he_IL.dic](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/blob/master/he_IL/he_IL.dic)

### For both Windows 64-bit ([3.20.1](https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/gedit/)) and 32-bit ([2.30.1](https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/gedit/2.30/)) versions

(Older versions of gedit are also available for Windows 32-bit but I haven't tried them.)

After installing gedit:

1. In File Explorer / Windows Explorer, find the gedit program folder (most likely `C:\Program Files\gedit` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\gedit`). (If you have installed gedit somewhere else then adjust the following paths accordingly.)
2. In the `share` subfolder (`C:\Program Files\gedit\share`), add a new `myspell` folder inside `share`, then add a `dicts` folder inside `myspell`.
3. Copy Hunspell / MySpell dictionaries into the `dicts` folder (`C:\Program Files\gedit\share\myspell\dicts`).

If the dictionaries are not recognized for some reason, they can also be placed in `C:\Program Files\gedit\share\enchant\myspell`.

### Extra steps required for 32-bit version

1. In File Explorer / Windows Explorer, add a series of new folders to create this path: `C:\msys\share\xml\iso-codes`.
2. Copy the XML files from `C:\Program Files\gedit\share\xml\iso-codes` into `C:\msys\share\xml\iso-codes`.

### Ispell and Aspell

Both versions of gedit appear to have Ispell support enabled, but I wasn't able to find any Ispell dictionaries that would work with these builds.

The 64-bit build (3.20.1) doesn't appear to have Aspell support enabled. The 32-bit build (2.30.1) includes the DLL for Aspell, but I don't think Aspell support was enabled in Enchant.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! There is also HSpell - Hebrew spell checker which might be relevant for others: http://hspell.ivrix.org.il/

Comment: When I try to save the dictionary files into both above mentioned locations - I get error: "You don't have permissions to save to this location! Contact the administrator to obtain permission" - what now? Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484 You would normally need to be the Administrator user (or have administrator rights) to copy or modify files in `C:\Program Files`. I would suggest asking your IT support to help copy the files.

Comment: I downloaded it to "Downloads" first and then copied it to the above location and that worked. Thank you very much!