# Gedit spellchecking on Windows is not working properly

Tags: windows, libreoffice, spell-check, dictionary, gedit

I am using Gedit, on Windows, to write a Latex document.

I noticed that the windows installation of Gedit does not come with preinstalled dictionaries for spellchecking (I don't know why), so I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1459045/how-to-install-spell-check-dictionaries-in-gedit-on-windows) that explains how to download and install dictionaries for Gedit on Windows. Wonderful, specifically I need to download the Italian dictionary, so I went to [this Github page](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries) and downloaded the folder. I then followed the procedure explained in the [previously linked post](https://superuser.com/questions/1459045/how-to-install-spell-check-dictionaries-in-gedit-on-windows): I went into the downloaded folder (the *LibreOffice* dictionaries), I then went into the **it_IT** folder and then I moved the files

- it_IT.aff
- it_IT.dic
- hyph_it_IT.dic

to the newly created **myspell/dicts** folder inside my Gedit installation, as the linked post explains.

After all this procedure I can finally see, when I open Gedit, the option to select the Italian Language; I selected it, I activated spellchecking, and it works! Wonderful! *But I then discovered a huge problem:* for some reason the spellchecking marks as wrong not only the truly mispelled words, but also *all the words with an accent in them*; those who know Italian know that this language is positively full of accents, so this is quite the problem; and also, for some reasons, the spellchecking marks as wrong the word "di", Italian for the English "of"; very suspicious.. Everything else wroks perfectly tho.

What is going on? How can I get functional Italian spellchecking on Windows's Gedit?

Comment: Try [this method](https://github.com/atom/spell-check/issues/161#issuecomment-336653098).

Comment: I did not understand how to apply the linked method. Furthermore the link appears to be about Atom and not Gedit. However I trust your competence on this topic: can you provide a step by step answer to my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Gedit and I chose the wrong link. I believe the basic idea in the link is logical, that the spellchecking dictionary files are not in a format that supports accented characters (such as UTF-8) and so they are badly recognized. But you will need to check this idea on your installation. Or wait for some more knowledgeable person to reply. Sorry I can't help more.